# How word association mining is generalization of n-gram language model

Tags: data-mining, text-mining, language-model

I am working on text mining (reading book...) author said **word association mining is actually the generalization of n-gram language model** Can you please tell how word association mining is generalization of n-gram language model.
For Me **word association mining** is finding symptomatic relation (finding co-occurring) words and **n-gram language model** is compare all n-words in query to suggest or return relevant documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Association rule mining will try to cover *frequent* concurrences of arbitrary length.

If you apply this (not just two term correlations) to text, you would indeed find n-grams without a fixed n.

Comment: Association mining is finding co-occurring expression (rather terms) or arbitrary length. Thank you I understood it.